# grouping in an excel pivot table with different year end and quartiles

Tags: excel, date, grouping, pivot-table

I have a pivot table with a lot of items currently grouped by date into quartiles and then months under that. My question is this, Our Financial year is not Jan to Jan so can I set up quartiles to reflect this? also our financial periods are not simply set months, they follow the months but are always full weeks around that. for example, P1 this year is `04/07/2015` - `07/08/2015`. and Q1 would be `04/07/2015` - `02/09/2015`.

Aside from manually grouping is there a way to set this up to happen automatically within Excel?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by pnuts in the question's comments:

> The most practical way may be to define the quarters (?) in your source data.

Comment: quite a simple solution that I hadn't thought of there. I think I probably could set up a few formulas that worked out what reporting period they were in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are at least using a Gregorian calendar, you may want to **subtract an offset from your dates** (i.e. # of days between 01-Jan-YYYY and DD-MMM-YYYY ... whereby the offset YYYY doesn't need to be the same as your date's YYYY). By this subtraction you get an "ordinal number" of the date within your business year.

- [offset] `=[FOY]-DATE(YEAR([FOY]),1,1)`

So with your year starting on `[FOY]=04-Jul-2015`, you have an offset of  of 184 days and a normalized date of

- [date_normalized] = `[current_date]-[offset]`

So 04-Jul-2015 will be shrunk to 01-Jan-2015. Now the quarter easily calculates to

- `=CEILING(MONTH([date_normalized])/3,1)`
- ... or `=VALUE(MID("111222333444",MONTH([date_normalized]),1))` ... if you prefer

For your not-quite-months always being full weeks, I suggest to calculate a week number by

- `=MOD(CEILING(([date_normalized]+1)/7,1)-1,52)+1`

to create a weekly reporting period 1 .. 52. With a further `=CEILING(.../4,1)` this can be converted to quasi-months having 4 weeks each.

Comment: I like this approach as well, good idea with the creating an ordinal date for reporting purposes. Many thanks

Comment: as often with date arithmetics, this concept may have some glitches in leap years, otherwise it should be rather robust ... glad you like it.